# Variable scope strange behavior in C++

Tags: c++, errno

My program invokes methods that will set `errno` when a failure occurs, I throw `errno` like an exception and catch it:

```
try
{
    if (-1 == truncate("/foo/bar.txt", 0))
    {
        throw errno;
    }
}
catch (const int errno)
{
    //log
}
```

Here I don't want to discuss the exception handling best practice topic. The truth is in the code above, `catch` block will not hit when the variable name in catch bracket is `errno`. This issue can be simplified to:

```
try
{
    throw 1999;
}
catch (const int errno)  //renaming "errno" to "e" works!!!
{
    //unreachable code here 
}
```

I know `errno` is a "special" name, but I thought C++ could handle same variable names defined in different scopes correctly.

```
//test.h
int my_number = 99;

//test.cpp
#include "test.h"
int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw 1999;
    }
    catch(int my_number)
    {
        std::cout << "in catch: " << my_number << std::endl;   //prints 1999
    }

    std::cout << my_number << std::endl;  //prints 99
}
```

The program is compiled in GNU5.4(happens in both C++11 and C++14). Can anyone explain the strange behavior?

Comment: The symbol `errno`  might be a *preprocessor macro*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so?

Comment: So the preprocessor will *replace* it with whatever it might be defined as, so you have e.g. `const int something_which_is_not_valid_in_a_delcaration`. In short, *never* define your own variables with the same name as a reserved symbol.

Comment: Macros don't care about scopes (that's one of their big problems).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Then why it compiles?

Comment: @DannyChen, it can throw something else. Or some multiline statement.

Comment: @DannyChen See the [comment by melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47808789/variable-scope-strange-behavior-in-c#comment82578709_47808809) to [StoryTellers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47808809/440558).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`errno` is a macro. So your exception handler contains some expanded tokens that most likely make very little sense. From the standard ([[errno]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/errno#1)):

> The contents of the header  are the same as the POSIX header
>   , except that errno shall be defined as a macro.

Comment: It's typically something like `(*__foo())`. Would that try to catch a function / function pointer?

Comment: @melpomene - Well it would expand to `const int (*__foo())`. That isn't a function pointer if my recollection of the rules for declarators holds, but a function. I have no idea why the OP's code isn't ill-formed in this case.

Comment: @melpomene - Had to result to using [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=const+int+%28*__foo%28%29%29). It does declare a function.

Comment: @DannyChen - Probably because you aren't looking at the header your compiler is actually using.

Comment: I press F12 in VSCODE on `catch(int errno)`, leads me to `/usr/include/error.h`, I think it is the correct one?

Comment: @DannyChen - VSCODE could be wrong. I suggest you pass that file through the processor only. For instance `g++ -E`. See what comes out the other side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161174/discussion-between-danny-chen-and-storyteller).